# Index for contextual suggestion like flipkart,amazon using elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, autosuggest

I have my products indexed with "title" and "categories" etc. Now in my autosuggest, I want something like Amazon/Flipkart,

for example if I query "green", I am suggested with "green tea","green shirt","green shirt for men" etc. Now my question being how is "green shirt for men", "green tea" .. being indexed to show in the suggestion.

One possible solution might be tagging a green shirt(product) with "green shirt for men".

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Please check auto suggest documentation in elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

for searching in all product items like in title, description, colour,categories etc, Use "_all" field of index and copy all the filed details into it, Then apply search on "_all" filed.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

You will get the expected result as you have mentioned in your asked question, Alos you can apply and use suggester API to search and get result like auto complete.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html

Hope this will help you.